# Block rewriting is not working

Tags: magento

I'm new to magento and I try to rewrite a block but it's not working 
here is what I tried

Pfay/MyProduct/Block/Catalog/Product/View.php

```
class Pfay_MyProduct_Block_Catalog_Product_View extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View
{

    public function canEmailToFriend()
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

config.xml

```
<config>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <catalog>               
                <rewrite>
                    <product_view>
                        Pfay_MyProduct_Block_Catalog_Product_View
                    </product_view>
                </rewrite>          
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
    </global>   
</config>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
<product_view>Pfay_MyProduct_Block_Catalog_Product_View</product_view>
```

Instead of

```
            <product_view>
                Pfay_MyProduct_Block_Catalog_Product_View
            </product_view>
```

Comment: Can i use my own function instead of canEmailToFriend()

Comment: Usually rewrite is not very good solution. But if you have no another variant - use it.